# How can I get the <select> tag option chosen by the user using Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a form whereby a user uploads a csv file, that csv file is then converted to a pandas dataframe and the column headers automatically populate the `<select>` tag options in the form.

I then want the user to select the column that they want and I want that column choice saved in a variable using Flask.

However, I'm having trouble retrieving the option that the user then selects from this select tag.

My template code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
     <legend>Text Analytics</legend>
     <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <label for="inputData" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Choose Data File:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
           <input type="file" class="form-control" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" name="inputData"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="upload">Upload</button>
        </div>
        {% if success %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong> {{success}}.
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Error:</strong> {{error}}.
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
     <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <label for="colSelect" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Select column for analysis:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <select class="form-control" name="colSelect" id="colSelect">
            {% for column in columns %}
                <option id="{{column}}">{{column}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
```

My Flask code:

```
@app.route('/textanalytics', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
error = None
success = None
columns = []
col = None
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.files['inputData'] == '':
        error = "No file selected"
    else:
        file = request.files['inputData']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            success = 'File uploaded'
            data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), header = 0, low_memory = False)
            columns = [i for i in data.columns]
            col = request.form.get('colSelect')
            return render_template('textanalytics.html', success = success, columns = columns, col = col)
        elif file and not allowed_file(file.filename):
            error = 'Incorrect file type, .csv only'
            return render_template('textanalytics.html', error = error)
return render_template('textanalytics.html', error = error, success = success, columns = columns, col = col)


app.add_url_rule('/uploads/<filename>', 'uploaded_file', build_only=True)
app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {'/uploads':  app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']})
```

As you can see, I am using `request.form.get('colSelect')` to retrieve the option but without any luck. It just returns `None` which is its initialised value.

I have a feeling it has to do with where I am placing that code but I am new to Flask and so could do with some help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give each `option` a `value`.

```
<option value="{{ column }}">{{ column }}</option>
```

Comment: Still no luck, it's just printing `None`.

Comment: Do you see the value included in your browser's request?

Comment: Nope, nothing. I added a `print col` statement in my flask file so I could see in my terminal if the value is selected, that's where I see the `None` value.

Comment: In your browser, if you look at the request it's sending, do you see the value? If you do, we've narrowed it down to a problem on the Flask side. If not, it's a problem on the browser side.

Comment: I just ran it again, I can't see the value it is sending.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. I took the form and separated it over two pages. So, the **File Upload** part was in its own form on a page called `textform1.html`. The uploaded file would be converted to a pandas dataframe and then a new page called `textform2.html` would be rendered. This page contained just the `<select>` part in its own form and thus I was then able to capture the selection from the user.